# VideoView not start after AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-videoview

VideoView displays white screen if start after loading it to the file using AsyncTask. Below is the code.

```
if (file.exists()) {
 loadVideo(file, infoImageView, infoVideoView);
}
else {
 new LoadToFile(file, infoImageView, infoVideoView).execute();
}
```

and my loadVideo function is

```
public void loadVideo(File file, ImageView imageView, final VideoView videoView) {
 imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 videoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
 videoView.start();
}
```

I have the loadToFile class defined inside the class where loadVideo function is there.

```
class LoadToFile extends AsyncTask {

 @Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
  downloadFile();
  return file;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
  File file = (File) o;
  loadVideo(file, imageView, videoView);
 }
}
```

When there is a file VideoView plays the video without any problem. But when I load the video to file using AsyncTask then the VideoView displays only white screen. The file is creating without any problem and if I restart the activity it plays without any problem.

Comment: Why are you downloading file ? You can directly play the url .

Comment: I need that for future use

Comment: If you worry about caching only then you can use https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache. Its works great . But if you really want to go your way then chek if file if written successfully or not .

Comment: Yes file written successfully and also when I restart the activity it plays the file.